# Showing a given set to be dense in an interval.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $S= \{\frac{p}{q} \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (0,1):  (p,q)=1,   q>N \}$.  Here $N$ is any fixed integer. I need to know if this is dense in (0,1) or not. Intuitively it seems to dense but I cannot prove analytically.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

For any rational $\frac{m}{n}$ with $\gcd(m,n)=1$ and $n\le N$ we consider the sequence $p_k$ where $p_1$ is the first prime number bigger than $N,$ $p_2$ the next prime and so on. Now

$$\frac{mp_k}{n(p_k+1)}\in S \quad \rm{and}\quad \frac{mp_k}{n(p_k+1)}\to \frac{m}{n}.$$